# Open current folder

Tags: directory

I recently reinstall ubuntu 16.04 and matlab. The problem is now, there is no "Open current folder' option available when I do the right-click in matlab. I have tried typing "filebrowser" in the command window but nothing happened. Besides, there is no "open/view outside matlab" option available for images. Thanks.

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: I guess I need to go to the matlab community forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing filebrowser in command windows opens the 'current folder toolbar', or selects that if it is already open. If you aren't able to get the 'open current folder' option after right clicking in 'current folder toolbar' then there is the path to current folder shown above the command window, you can just visit that using regular system file browser/explorer, and if you do not have that address bar then just type 'pwd' without the quotes in command window and you get the current folder which you could visit using regular system file browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @iamnotgoogle. Yes, that can be one of the ways to open the folder. But I was just wondering, why the current installed matlab does not have the option the open the current folder. It did have that before..

Comment: @mohdalmie Well if you installed the same version of matlab then it means it should have that option, but since you were not able to open it i gave alternate ways to open the current folder.